# MSBuild target PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder cannot be found when deploying

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, pipeline

Deploying a Web Application Project from VS2010 RTM causes an error in MSBuild. It complains that the PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder target cannot be found.

Is there any way to further diagnose this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and when I looked in the .csproj file for my web application I had the following lines...

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(Solutions.VSVersion)' == '8.0'" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(Solutions.VSVersion)' == '9.0'" />
```

I guess this happened since I had recently upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010.  So it looks like the during the conversion process it got all screwed up.  To fix it I just replaced those lines with ...

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

After that everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 9):

I've seen the answer given by brodie in several places online, which is strange to me because this task (**PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolde**r) is not even contained in this target (Microsoft.WebApplication.targets):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

If you actually go and find this file (on an x64 machine it's in ***C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets***, or the version 12.0 equivalent if you're using VS2013) and open it in a text viewer, you'll see it's not there..

It's actually contained in the file that Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi mentions, which is the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file (***C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets***).

So to get this into your MSBuild/.csproj file, include the following:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
```

Comment: Good call, I find the above accepted answer odd, too. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Visual Studio 2010 installed on the machine where you are trying to build? If so then look for a file located at **%Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets** it should have that target. If it doesn't then those files may have been corrupted and probably reparing your VS 2010 install should fix it.

I think the Web Deployment targets/tasks are shipped with VS itself and not the .NET framework, so you need VS installed (or you can manually configure the machine)/

Comment: reinstalling my computer. vs2010 installed to clean pc and still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post It still provided some great help!

My setup is using a remote host for Automation of a project built in VS2013.
The remote host doesn't contain all the VS2013 targets when you solely install MSBuild 12.0 and this resulted in the 'Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets' file not existing.

To get around this target error I had to copy the files from my local VS2013 path and copy this to the remote host in the equivalent location.

Comment: Yes as this is a different setup to working on a local install of VS.

Comment: I was getting this error with the use of MS build without visual studio installed and was missing the 'Web' folder from %Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\    The required TARGET file sits inside the 'Web' folder as Sayed showed so my solution was to obtain the 'Web' folder from a full VS2103 install and then copy the folder over.  Hope this helps in some form :)

Comment: you can edit your answer and add the additional details, that would be better visible than your comment :-)