# What does the pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder target do?

Tags: msbuild

I've seen `msbuild` commands pass `/t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder` as a target. On searching the Internet, I've found many forum and question/answers posts about this target. That said, I've found no official documentation.

- What does this target do?
- Where does Microsoft document it?

This target usually goes along with a `_PackageTempDir` property.

My best guess is that the target and property together mean that, before deployment, copy all files to the specified package temp directory.

Comment: do you find authoritative answer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a Web Application specific default target.
As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214583) it is in the following file:

> It's actually contained in the file that Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi mentions, which is the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets).

You can check what its content [here](https://github.com/Ky7m/TypeScript.MSBuildTask/blob/master/source/Typescript.MSBuildTask/tools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/Web/Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets). (I found a copy on github)

Neither I could find the mentioned target among any documentation. However, there is a documentation of `msbuild` on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/tree/main/documentation) with some fancy figures. Also, there are other documentation fragments on Microsoft's documentation about [Default build targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019#default-build-targets) or [Common target files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-dot-targets-files?view=vs-2019).